# Дотримання норм сучасного українського правопису

Tags: discussion, rules, nonstandard-grammar

Мене просто спантеличує величезна кількість "прогресивних" змін, які останнім часом намагалися (намагаються) запровадити в український правопис. Серед небагатьох із них, що я зустрів на ukrainian.stackexchange.com:

[Вживання літери “И” на початку слова](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/397/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%94-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%98-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

[Варіянт, діялог, спеціяльний, діялект...](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/870/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82)

На мою думку, мова повинна бути простою, зрозумілою і зручною в спілкуванні, а не **створювати "...звичайним людям повний mess в голові"** ([@Bohdan Kuts](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/870/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82)). Я не хочу при розмові кожного разу заглядати в словник, щоб дізнатися "сучасну" вимову звичних слів, я не хочу, щоб мої батьки дивувалися з кожної другої фрази телевізійного ведучого...

Ні! Я ні в якому разі не проти змін і нововведень, я за те, щоб робити це поступово і прагматично. Безумовно, потрібно очищати мову від перекручень (як от "[чахлик невмирущий](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/553/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E)"), розробляти ефективні механізми запозичення іноземних слів. Але робити це слід обережно і враховувати, що цілі покоління виросли на деяких, нехай навіть "не ідеальних" правилах правопису.

Шановні академіки та пуристи! **Кожного разу, коли намагаєтесь просунути якесь нововведення в український правопис, подумайте, чи дійсно користь від цього нововведення переважить незручності пов'язані з ламанням усталених традицій та перенавчанням мільйонів українців**

> Благими намірами вимощена дорога в пекло

Я вважаю, що ініціативи на зразок "давайте з завтрашнього дня замість "Х" будемо вживати "Г" в словах іншомовного походження, а в наших перестанемо І-кати і почнемо И-кати", можуть стати останнім цвяхом в труні української мови.

Гадаю, що ніхто не буде заперечувати, що українська мова знаходиться в важкому становищі навіть в себе вдома. Її сотні років вбивали і принижували, тому вона дуже слабка і намагання покласти її на хірургічний стіл та  зробити їй ще десяток операцій (часом, зовсім не потрібних), враховуючи її стан - це теж саме, що просто зарізати її. Давайте дамо їй можливість стати дужчою, а вже після цього почнемо позбавлятися жирку, виправляти поставу, коригувати ніс та інші місця.

Я розумію, що декому потрібно писати дисертації, здобувати вчені звання. Але варто розмежовувати вивчення минулого від спроб повернути його в майбутнє (без вагомих на те причин).

Тож, давайте дотримуватися чинних правил правопису, а якщо комусь хочеться "щегольнуть" знаннями маловідомих (простому люду) правописів, робіть це в вузьких академічних колах. Інакше, замість "покращень", наступить безлад, наша рідна мова стане сучасною та модною, як Свирид Петорвич Голохвастов, та, на жаль, нікому не зрозумілою, смішною і не потрібною

P.S.: я не є мовознавцем і не маю відношення до мовотворення. Я виклав думку звичайного українця, який вчився в українській школі, використовує українську мову в побуті і дуже хоче, щоб вона залишалася такою ж милозвучною та зрозумілою.

Comment: -1: What is your question?

Comment: @bytebuster: розумію, що стаття не відповідає вимогам сайту, однак вирішив опублікувати її оскільки неодноразово помічав використання  серед активних користувачів маловідомих/забутих правописів, що на мою думку призведе до виникнення непорозумінь серед звичайних користувачів і вносить анархію в чинний правопис. Я можу переписати статтю і зробити щось на зразок, "Чи варто дотримуватися правил чинного правопису?", але тоді це викличе  дискусію і ...знову ж таки її закриття.

Comment: Перепрошую, але будь-яке запитання виду «чи варто?…» приречені на те, щоб бути opinion-based, а значить, і оффтопіком. Одній людині «варто», іншій — ні.

Comment: @bytebuster: мені теж шкода, що я віддав за вас голос в номінації на роль модератора. Ви дивитесь лише на "формат" повідомлення і зовсім не звертаєте увагу на його суть. Схоже, що вам все одно, що діється на сайті, тільки б це відповідало "формату".

Comment: Будь ласка, зніміть свій голос, якщо передумали. Це ніяк не вплине на те, що це запитання є opinion-based і not-a-real-question.

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko чи свідомі ви того, що ви, доки розказували цим постом як тут себе поводити іншим, зробили декілька логічних помилок? як, наприклад, [Hasty generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_generalization) та [Appeal to fear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_fear). Саме тому *суть* як ви кажете вашого посту **робить його не у форматі спільноти**. +1 vote for close

Comment: @chizh я чесно зізнався ким є і не збираюся нікого "вчити. За "неформат" і надмірну емоційність я теж з себе не знімаю відповідальності, але мене дивує байдужість до проблеми яку я намагався підняти

Comment: @bytebuster: я хотів зняти свій голос, але він заблокований.

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, Ви можете висловити свою думку там у вигляді коментаря англійською. Скажу чесно — я не вважаю bytebuster ідеальною кандидатурою, він не в усьому мені подобається. **Але:** він найактивніший за нас — і це багато вартує. **Бо бути правим, лежачи на дивані**, кожен дурень може (особливо в мене класно це виходить). А от як робити — то ми завжди робимо неідеально. Тому я б радив змінити думку щодо нього і знайти спільну мову. (Я вважаю, що Ви підняли дуже корисну тему, але формат справді не дуже — треба було починати з висловлення думок всіх, а не з власної агітації.) ІМХО.

Comment: @Sasha: я не збирався нікого ображати своїм повідомленням, не "тикав пальцями" та намагався бути ввічливим. Якщо когось образили використані гіперболи та алегорії, прошу вибачення, я не розрахував, що це сприйметься так вороже.

Comment: @Sasha: я не берусь оцінювати bytebuster, однак, мені здається, він занадто захопився "мінусуванням".

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, я не сприйняв нічого вороже (перепрошую, якщо з моїх коментарів так здалося — може, я просто невдало щось висловив). Я просто буквально появнив, чому вважаю bytebuster'а хорошою кандидатурою (незважаючи на те, що він, як і всі ми, не 100% ідеальний). (Зараз подумав, може, це пояснення тут і недоречне.)

Comment: @Sasha: не варто вибачатись, ви поки єдиний хто спробував мене зрозуміти. Я взагалі ні на кого не ображаюсь і не шукаю нічиєї поваги, просто не хочеться, щоб було "хотіли як краще, а вийшло як завжди" (тобто, не перетворили ukrainian.stackexchange.com з інструменту вдосконалення мови в інструмент її перекручення і поширення насмішок)

Comment: Ееем, можливо, просто я не зрозумів, проте який стосунок це запитання (заклик) має стосунок до stackexchange (як ukrainian, так і meta.ukrainian)? Проблема справді важлива, але ж Ви звертаєтеся до "академіків та пуристів".

Comment: @обставинниковийТранспозитор: я не мав можливості познайомитися з кожним із вас особисто, тож припустив, що раз ви обговорюєте такі "високі теми" як альтернативні правописи та  невідомі мені до цих пір "проекти", то маєте бути академіками)

Comment: @Sasha, пропоную обговорювати не користувачів, а дії. Яка дія була неправильною? Down+Close vote допису, який опублікований під виглядом запитання, але в дійсності чітко вписується у прямо прописаний off-topic на сторінці http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask: **«your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”»** — це було неправильним? Чи ще щось? Поясніть, будьте ласкаві. :)

Comment: @bytebuster, у даному випадку це було якраз обговорення користувача. І, не знаю, помітили Ви чи ні, але я якраз став на Ваш бік, намагаючись передати Олександру Матвієнку своє бачення, що, так, людина Ви неідеальна, але у Вас багато плюсів для ролі модератора. Вважаю обговорення особистості кандидата на роль модератора прийнятною, бо від модераторів вимагаються в тому числі й особисті якості («exhibit those intangible traits discussed in „A Theory of Moderation“»), а не лише лише зроблені раніше дії. Але якщо Ви хочете, можу прибрати свій коментар.

Comment: @Sasha, мені здається, що не важливо, на чий бік ви стали. Обговорення людей, а не вчинків, — це no-no. Чесно кажу.

Comment: @bytebuster, (1) proof? (2) і до кандидатів у модератори? (і в постах, що їх висувають кандидатами?)

Comment: @Sasha, (1) Sure. [be-nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). **Don't be a jerk**. […] **Focus on the post, not the person.** That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny"). (2), одразу — це запитання не обговорює кандидатів. Тому коментарі на іншу тему — як мінімум, оффтопік.

Comment: @bytebuster, (1) Ви інтерпретуєте, по-моєму, дуже специфічно; (2) а в номінаціях і комантарях до номінацій? (офтопік — так, мабуть; але це коментарі.)

Comment: А номінації для цього і призначені (provided that you keep politeness and focus on posts, not the person). Цей допис не є номінацією.

Comment: @Sasha: не витрачайте даремно свій час, бо я ще в 2-му коментарі визнав, що порушив певні правила stackexchange і  думка моя про bytebuster сформувалася досить чітко, особливо після того, як він в чаті раптом запропонував вам "вичистити псевдо-запитання, їх все одно мало хто читає" (хоча до появи цього псевдо-запитання його це не хвилювало)

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, давайте не будемо несправедливі: насправді він однаково суворо ставиться до [будь](//meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/154/4)-[яких](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/87/4) запитань, що не відповідають формальним критеріям (не містять знаку питання в буквальному сенсі, занадто довгі тощо).

Comment: Класика України: посварилися замість того щоб запропонувати виправлення чи переформатування питання.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a petition leading to an open-ended discussion, not a genuine question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olexandr Matviienko, більшість з нас не є академіками. Принаймні я є просто звичайним українцем, що хоче зробити інформацію про українську мову більш доступною. Припускаю, що більшість інших тут — також.

Я поставив Вам за це питання "+1", бо Ви підняли дуже важливу тему.

Але Ви змішуєте в одному питанні кілька (на мій погляд) різних речей:

1. **Чи можна питати про альтернативні правописи/діалекти?** (Прямо, наприклад, «Як за правилами проекту-99 мало би писатися слово „існує“?» — чи непрямо, наприклад, «чого деякі телеканали кажуть „ефір“, а деякі „етер“?» або «що таке „тремпель“?»)

   <sub>Я особисто вважаю, що питати про будь-що стосовно мови має бути дозволено. (Якщо це, звісно, справді питання, а не неприкрита пропаганда.)</sub>
2. **Чи можна**, відповідаючи на запитання, **висвітлювати якусь інформацію про альтернативні правописи/діалекти?**

   <sub>Моя особиста думка — в цілому, так, можна, але з великими обмеженнями:</sub>

   - <sub>Якщо запитання користувача безпосередньо стосується якогось альтернативного правопису/діалекту (тобто те, що він хоче отримати погляд на речі з точки зору певного правопису/діалекту, прямо зазначено в тексті питання) — то Ви, звісно, вільні надавати інформацію про цей правопис/діалект.</sub>
   - <sub>Якщо же запитання користувача безпосередньо не стосується якогось альтернативного правопису/діалекту (тобто в тексті питання прямо не зазначено, що він хоче отримати погляд на речі з точки зору певного правопису/діалекту), то:</sub>

     1. <sub>Кожна відповідь має розкривати інформацію **в першу чергу** з точки зору стандартного літературного діалекту і офіційного правопису (інакше це може призводити до введення читача в оману).</sub>
     2. <sub>Надавати інформацію про альтернативні правописи/діалекти **дозволено і навіть заохочується** (бо це корисна інформація, що дозволяє читачу глибше зрозуміти мову), але:</sub>

        - <sub>має бути очевидно, де межа між офіційним і альтернативним (інакше це введення в оману);</sub>
        - <sub>офіційна точка зору має бути хоча б коротко висвітлена/згадана (інакше відповідь неповна).</sub>
3. **Чи можна писати сам текст питання/відповіді нестандартним правописом/діалектом?** (А не цитати в ньому, мовляв, «як Ви розумієте оці „…“ слова пісні?»)

   О, це складне питання…

   Я довго над цим думав ще на етапі «definition» (до відкриття сайту).

   <sub>Я вирішив, як то кажуть, **пустити все самопливом**:</sub>

   - <sub>хто хоче писати нестандартно — хай пише/пробує;</sub>
   - <sub>кому це не подобається — хай його критикує/мінусує/редагує;</sub>
   - <sub>у нас вільне суспільство, врешті решт; якщо альтернатива зустріне великий опір (її носія критикуватимуть/редагуватимуть/мінусуватимить), то, може, йому набридне і він перестане тут нестандартно писати чи піде з сайту; якщо не зустрічатиме — ну отже всіх усе влаштовує і проблеми самої нема.</sub>

   Але може це рішення помилкове. Я відкритий до інших думок.

Тепер, Olexandr'е Matviienko, слухаю Вашу думку. **З *якими конкретно* з цих пунктів Ви не згодні?**

(Я, власне, думав написати про це на ме́та. Але потім не став, думав, все всім очевидно. Але можемо відкрити окреме обговорення на ме́ті (обсудити конкретні аспекти).)

Comment: 1. Я не проти дослідження альтернативних правописів, діалектів. Навпаки, я вважаю, що цей сайт прекрасне місце для проведення подібних дослдіжень

Comment: 2. "Має бути очевидно, де межа між офіційним і альтернативним" - це має бути обов'язковою вимогою в відповідях.  Припустимо, хтось зайде на сайт і побачить, що в словнику написано **иньший** (http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/399/116) і так і напише,  адже, stackexchange.com є авторитетним ресурсом.

Comment: 3. Що стосується запитань: мені теж складно відповісти на це запитання. Однак, я гадаю, що з масовим використанням сайту піде потік малоосвічених користувачів, яким буде важко/неможливо визначити який у них правопис/діалект, тому недоцільно висувати якість додаткові вимоги для них. Гарним вирішенням цієї проблеми була б доброзичлива спільнота редакторів, однак я не уявляю скільки це вимагатиме ресурсів.

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, гадаю, це окреме важливе питання, яке й справді варто поставити на ме́ті. Бо, наприклад, Yello Sky принципово пише "инший". І хоча за чинним правописом правильно "інший" особисто я не вважаю правильним редагувати його повідомлення, щоб було "інший"...

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, щось я не зрозумів: Ваше «3» — це відповідь на моє «3», чи ні?

Comment: @Sasha: це мій "3-ій пункт". Проте, я повністю підтримую Вашу відповідь

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, ага, я зрозумів. Тобто Ви повністю згодні з моїми 3 пунктами. І ще додатково висловили Ваші.

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, Ви щось типу [такого](//meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/154/4) мали на увазі чи ні?

Comment: @Sasha Не зовсім... Я мав на увазі саме фразу "Гарним вирішенням цієї проблеми була б доброзичлива спільнота редакторів" і пропонував поставити дуже вузьке питання "Чи варто виправляти в постах те, що не відповідає чинному правопису, проте відповідає іншим правописам (на кшталт 'инший')?". Втім, ви даєте можливу відповідь у §3, може цього наразі достатньо, доки не почалися війни редагувань з цього приводу :)