# Про альтернативні правописи і нестандартні діалекти

Tags: discussion, rules, nonstandard-grammar

Тут Olexandr Matviienko підняв [цікаве питання](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/151/4).

Тож пропоную сформувати політику спільноти щодо альтернативних правописів і нестандартних діалектів.

«Проект» я виклав нижче у вигляді окремої відповіді. Слухаю Вашу критику або альтернативні «проекти». Але кожен «проект» має відповідати мінімум на три питання:

1. Чи можна запитувати про альтернативні правописи і нестандартні діалекти? (Прямо: «як за правилами проекту-99 мало би писатися слово „існує“?» — чи непрямо: «чого деякі телеканали кажуть „ефір“, а деякі „етер“?», «що таке „тремпель“?» тощо)
2. Чи можна висвітлювати інформацію про альтернативні правописи і нестандартні діалекти? (У запитанні або відповіді.)
3. Чи можна сам текст запитання, відповіді чи коментаря писати альтернативним правописом чи нестандартним діалектом? (Мова не про цитати: «як Ви думаєте, чому Грушевський пише „*хотіло ся*“?» — а про сам текст: «у Т. Шевченка *вживають ся* різні вирази.»)

Comment: Думаю це краще у вигляді однієї (чи декількох) відповідей оформити, щоб можна було голосувати за/проти і коментувати.

Comment: @Artemix, добре, можу. Я наразі схиляюсь до однієї. Бо якщо я відповідь на підпитання №1, підпитання №2 і підпитання №3 оформлю як різні відповіді, то при швидкому перегляді сторінки здаватимуться, що то конкуруючі варіанти (а не відповіді на різні підпитання) — особливо як вони будуть впереміш із іншими (чужими) пропозиціями.

Answer (score 5):

#### § 1. Чи можна запитувати про альтернативні правописи і нестандартні діалекти?

<sup>(Прямо: «як за правилами проекту-99 мало би писатися слово „існує“?» — чи непрямо: «чого деякі телеканали кажуть „ефір“, а деякі „етер“?», «що таке „тремпель“?» тощо)</sup>

**Так**, запитувати будь-що стосовно мови дозволено.
(Якщо це, звісно, справді запитання, а не неприкрита пропаганда чогось.)

---

#### § 2. Чи можна висвітлювати інформацію про альтернативні правописи і нестандартні діалекти?

<sup>(У запитанні або відповіді.)</sup>

В цілому, так, але з обмеженнями:

- Якщо запитання користувача безпосередньо стосується якогось альтернативного правопису/діалекту (тобто те, що він хоче отримати погляд на речі з точки зору певного правопису/діалекту, прямо зазначено в тексті питання) — то Ви, **звісно**, вільні надавати інформацію про цей правопис/діалект.
- Якщо же запитання користувача безпосередньо не стосується якогось альтернативного правопису/діалекту (тобто в тексті питання не зазначено прямо, що він хоче отримати погляд на речі з точки зору певного правопису/діалекту), то:

  1. Кожна відповідь має розкривати інформацію **в першу чергу** з точки зору стандартного літературного діалекту і офіційного правопису (інакше це може призводити до введення читача в оману).
  2. Надавати інформацію про альтернативні правописи/діалекти **дозволено і навіть заохочується** (бо це корисна інформація, що дозволяє читачу глибше зрозуміти мову), але:

     - має бути очевидно, де межа між офіційним і альтернативним (інакше це введення в оману);
     - офіційна точка зору має бути хоча б коротко висвітлена/згадана (інакше відповідь неповна).

---

#### § 3. Чи можна сам текст запитання, відповіді чи коментаря писати альтернативним правописом чи нестандартним діалектом?

<sup>(Мова не про цитати: «як Ви думаєте, чому Грушевський пише „*хотіло ся*“?» — а про сам текст: «у Т. Шевченка *вживають ся* різні вирази.»)</sup>

Це «сіра зона»:

- Ви (теоретично) можете писати текст так, як Вам заманеться.
- Але інші користувачі (теоретично) можуть критикувати Вас за це, голосувати через це проти Ваших дописів або в крайньому разі навіть виправляти це, як помилки (чи то справді не знаючи, що це альтернативна система, чи то роблячи вигляд, що не знають, чи то вважаючи, що їй тут не місце).
- Якщо Вам вдалося знайти спільну мову з іншими користувачами — вважайте, що Ваш спосіб письма прийнятний. Якщо Ваш спосіб письма викликає опір — це є Вашою проблемою (а не спільноти). Також враховуйте, що сприйняття Вашого способу письма (самого навіть незмінного) може з часом змінюватися.

Comment: я підтримую Вашу позицію, але з деякими уточненнями:

Comment: 1. Параграф 2.2: "**Надавати інформацію про альтернативні правописи/діалекти дозволено і навіть заохочується**" не думаю, що варто без ініціативи користувача, який поставив запитання, цього робити. Припустимо, іноземець спробує дізнатися як перекласти те чи інше слово, а йому у відповідь видадуть 3 офіційні варіанти і ще 10-к альтернативних/діалектів. Людина замість того, щоб отримати конкретну відповідь отримає ще десяток запитань у своїй голові. Тому, думаю краще **прибрати "заохочується"**

Comment: 2. Параграф 3: "**Чи можна сам текст запитання, відповіді чи коментаря писати альтернативним правописом чи нестандартним діалектом?**" - погоджуюсь із **запитаннями** і сумніваюсь з **коментарями**, але **не підтримую із відповідями**: вони мають відповідати п.2 (адже на них потім будуть посилатися інші сайти). Все ж мають бути сформовані чіткі правила для того, щоб "мінусувати" когось. Інакше просто переможе сильніший, а не розумніший і це стане зайвим приводом для суперечок. Вважаю, що це питання є досить важливим, його слід вирішити на ранній стадій а не відкладати на потім

Comment: Згоден з п.3, хоча вважаю, що мінусувати за *варіянт* чи *Гемінґвея* — занадто. Ukr.SE **не є** авторитетним джерелом, тому я маю право писати тут як заманеться. Ба більше, ми **вимагаємо** посилання на авторитетні джерела. І якщо хтось не в силі перевірити за авторитетним словником *варіант* чи *варіянт*, то це його проблема. Мова — не сталий продукт, вона піддається мутаціям так само, як і будь-який інший організм. Якщо девіантний *варіянт* "торкає" лише мене, то він при мені й залишиться, але придушувати такі відхили — це фашизм. Давайте тоді й новотвори заборонимо, бо їх немає в словнику.

Comment: @NashBridges: "Ukr.SE не є авторитетним джерелом", якщо це дійсно так, то тоді дійсно це питання не є актуальним. Але **навіщо тоді розводити тут демагогії на теми "А як правильно...?", якщо кожен буде робити "як заманеться"**? На мою думку, якщо кожен буде тут писати як йому заманеться, то через деякий час цей сайт нічим не відрізнятиметься від громадського паркану. Я, наприклад, часто зловживаю суржиком при розмові з близькими і знайомими, але в публічному спілкуванні намагаюсь дотримуватися чинних правил, а не використовувати цю звичку як засіб самовираження

Comment: @NashBridges: "придушувати такі відхили — це фашизм"... тоді за вашою логікою всі вчителі - "фашисти" бо не дають дітям писати так, як їм хочеться, чи не так? Ніхто не забороняє Вам спілкуватися тією мовою/діалектом, якою ви хочете, однак, там де є певні правила, треба їх дотримуватися. Проте, якщо таких правил немає, робіть що завгодно, але я тоді не бачу сенсу в існуванні цього сайту

Comment: @OlexandrMatviienko, NashBridges, прошу, вирішуйте як хочете, тілько не сваріться. Я трішки пізніше приєднаюся до діалогу, як аврал на роботі скінчиться. Я давно вже збираюся Олександру Матвієнку відповісти — тільки думки не міг зібрати.

Comment: OlexandrMatviienko, @NashBridges, прошу, вирішуйте як хочете, тілько не сваріться. Я трішки пізніше приєднаюся до діалогу, як аврал на роботі скінчиться. Я давно вже збираюся Олександру Матвієнку відповісти — тільки думки не міг зібрати.

Comment: Я не мав наміру нікого ображати і навіть не думав, що "дотримання правил чинного правопису" може сприйматися як фашизм. Свої думки нікому не нав'язую, якщо вони викликають негативну реакцію - не буду заважати

Comment: Re: *«Якщо Ваш спосіб письма викликає опір»*: опір — це, наприклад, downvote.