# Чи доречне використання іншої термінолоґії і чи не шкодить воно взаєморозумінню?

Tags: discussion, nonstandard-grammar

[Значення, походження немов-приростка зу-](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D1%83)

Тут Follower пише "немов-приросток". Я це зможу зрозуміти тільки якщо перед цим прочитаю інше питання-відповідь, де пояснюється вся ця термінолоґія. Людина, яка прийшла на сайт і вирішила почитати питання і відповіді, просто не зрозуміє без додаткового пошуку, що це таке. Може, варто через слеш пояснювати, або у дужках, що мається на увазі?

Comment: Погоджуюся. Доречно мати словник термінів для видань, які використовують таку термінологію, але для нових питань краще вживати загальноприйняту, з якою усі знайомі зі школи.

Comment: На мою думку, це запитання вже було поставлене [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/154/) (§3). Щоправда, там лише одна відповідь, авторська, але тему розкрито.

Comment: Хех, мене теж здивувала термінологія у запитанні (так би мовити: якщо людина пише відповідь, то ми їй вдячні за допомогу і, мабуть, варто дозволяти їй трішки неявно просувати свої погляди (альтернативну термінологію тощо), але в межах розумного (у випадку термінології — щонайменше з поясненнями); але якщо це запитання, то це виглядає трішки дивно — звертатися за допомогою до спільноти, використовуючи термінологію, яку частина спільноти може не розуміти, і притому без пояснень, і притому не лише неофіційна термінологія («приросток»), а й, наскільки я бачу, власні слова («немов-приросток»)).

Comment: Але я б на Вашому місці все-таки сам не виправляв (не кажу, що зробили неправильно, але я б особисто не став би). Принаймні без якогось остаточного суспільного рішення. Врешті-решт, якщо людині подобається висловлюватися певним чином, і іншим від цього шкоди немає, то нехай; а так раптом людина образиться… Я б, мабуть, просто попросив і суттю прохання було б, мабуть, не прибрати, а зробити виноски, щоби питання було зрозумілим без контексту (наприклад: «Приросток (за такою-то термінологією) — префікс. Немовби-приросток — цим я хотів сказати, що…»).

Comment: @Sasha тому я спочатку спитав і саме так і запропонував зробити, потім почекав, а потім вирішив виправити і залишити до моменту, коли Follower вийде на зв’язок, щоби люди поки що могли все зрозуміти. Якщо Follower схоче - він зможе повернути "приросток" і потім пояснити значення пересічному користувачу. Якщо йому все одно - може не робити цього.